# OCR - PDF to HTML - get data from elements

Tags: php, html, pdf, ocr

I need to analyze some PDF files and extract data from them

I use `pdftohtml` to convert the PDF to HTML

```
pdftohtml -s -i 001.pdf
```

E.g. I need to get the amount `60,00` under the heading `Fragt` in the HTML document. I can do some regular expressions to find `Fragt` but how do I get the nearest element either under the `Fragt` element or to the right of the element?

Is there a quick tool or something to do the data extraction more convenient, or do I have to calculate the positions relative to each of the elements?

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<head>
<title>001-html.html</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
 <br/>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    p {margin: 0; padding: 0;}  .ft10{font-size:13px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft11{font-size:13px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft12{font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft13{font-size:19px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft14{font-size:10px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft15{font-size:12px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft16{font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft17{font-size:13px;line-height:21px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft18{font-size:19px;line-height:27px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft19{font-size:11px;line-height:18px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft110{font-size:11px;line-height:16px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft111{font-size:10px;line-height:15px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
    .ft112{font-size:11px;line-height:17px;font-family:Times;color:#000000;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#A0A0A0" vlink="blue" link="blue">
<div id="page1-div" style="position:relative;width:892px;height:1261px;">
<p style="position:absolute;top:385px;left:609px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Deres&#160;ref.:</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:69px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Varenr.</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:203px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Beskrivelse</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:519px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Antal</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:572px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Enhed</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:662px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>A-pris</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:719px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>%</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:426px;left:797px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Beløb</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:489px;left:68px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">tal140</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:489px;left:203px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">Husnummer 1 H. 40 cm.</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:489px;left:795px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;236,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:489px;left:570px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">Stk.</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:489px;left:654px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;118,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:489px;left:508px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;2,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:509px;left:68px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">tal440</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:509px;left:203px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">Husnummer 4 H. 40 cm.</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:509px;left:795px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;236,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:509px;left:570px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">Stk.</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:509px;left:654px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;118,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:509px;left:508px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;2,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:529px;left:68px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">bog</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:529px;left:203px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">Bogstav H. 40 cm.</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:529px;left:796px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;118,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:529px;left:570px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">Stk.</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:529px;left:654px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;118,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:529px;left:508px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft15">&#160;1,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1014px;left:350px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft16">OBS !&#160;Vi holder ferielukket i uge 28-29-30</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1104px;left:785px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>&#160;812,50</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1131px;left:680px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>09-07-2016</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1104px;left:632px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft16">&#160;162,50</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1131px;left:216px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Netto kontant</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1104px;left:162px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft16">&#160;590,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1086px;left:792px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>DKK</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1131px;left:153px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Betaling&#160;</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1131px;left:539px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Betales senest den .:&#160;</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1086px;left:137px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Netto-beløb</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1086px;left:276px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Fragt</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1086px;left:441px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Momspligtigt beløb</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1086px;left:569px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Momsbeløb 25 %</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1086px;left:691px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft12"><b>Faktura-total&#160;</b></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1104px;left:287px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft16">&#160;60,00</p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1104px;left:511px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft16">&#160;650,00</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How exactly is this problem related to C++?

Comment: A solution in C++ or PHP maybe

Comment: Ok, so you're just fishing and it's not really a C++ _or_ PHP issue. got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will find the closest element, it's in JS and you'll need to paste the whole block into the code you posted above.

On one hand, php can find the elements if given a document fragment - on the other, there's no `getComputedStyle` function to make things so much easier. I suspect you'll need to parse the HTML yourself in order to get the position of each element.

This code merely highlights the element whose top-left is the closest to the top-left of the target element. This will fail in many, many cases - you can improve and modify it in a way that suits your needs.

**Expected output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<script>
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function allByTag(tag){return document.getElementsByTagName(tag)}
function replace(haystack, needle, replacement){ return haystack.replace(new RegExp(needle, 'g'), replacement); }
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded);
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    var options = { elemType: 'p', elemTxt: 'Fragt' };
    var tgt = findElement(options);
    var tgtPos = getElemTopLeft(tgt);

    var elems = allByTag('p');
    var minDist=1000000, bestElem;
    elems.forEach( 
                    function(elem, index, array)
                    {
                        if (elem != tgt)
                        {
                            var p2Pos = getElemTopLeft(elem);
                            if (distBetween(tgtPos, p2Pos) < minDist)
                            {
                                minDist = distBetween(tgtPos, p2Pos);
                                bestElem = elem;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
    bestElem.style.border = "solid 4px red";
}

function getElemTopLeft(elem)
{
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
    return { left: parseInt(style["left"]), top: parseInt(style["top"]) };
}

function distBetween(point1, point2)
{
    var dX = point2.left - point1.left;
    var dY = point2.top - point1.top;
    return Math.sqrt( dX*dX + dY*dY );
}

function findElement( options )
{
    var elems = allByTag( options.elemType );
    var resultIndex = -1;
    elems.forEach( function(elem, index, array){if (elem.textContent == options.elemTxt) resultIndex = index;} );
    if (resultIndex == -1)
        return undefined;
    return elems[resultIndex];
}
</script>
```